# Htaccess mod_rewrite - slash

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have rewrite part of htaccess like

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?section=articles&page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?section=articles&page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?section=articles&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]*)$ /index.php?section=articles&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/$ /index.php?section=articles [L]
RewriteRule ^articles$ /index.php?section=articles [L]
```

But when I write for example `/articles/detail/1` it works properly, but when I add backslash into the end (`/articles/detail/1/`), it doesn't.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks allright, perhaps there's a problem in the accepting index.php, what does your rewrite log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually problem is indeed placement of trailing slash in your rule. **Trailing slash should be made optional in all the rules** like this:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?section=articles&page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?section=articles&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/?$ /index.php?section=articles [L]
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as the example, for the rules are impicitely 'OR'?

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk No it is not same. Please see carefully. For ex. in OP's regex `^articles$` and `^articles/([^/]*)$` will both match the same URI: `/article` hence 2nd rule will never be applied. That's why I have used `([^/]+)` everywhere instead of `([^/]*)`.

Comment: Right you are, these rules sometimes are cracking my head.